# CSS nth-child ignores the first 3 elements, stylize the other 3 and repeats. Possible?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know that nth-child is for every nth element, but maybe it's possible to ignore the first 3 elements, stylize the other 3 and repeat for a huge list. I tried to write that every 4n+1,5n+1 and 6n+1 would change, but this also includes 8, 15 and so on, which I don't want to be stylized.
All my attempts to nth-child were fruitless.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to only style 4,5,6?  Or do you want to style 4,5,6, 10,11,12, 16,17,18, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to select every other group of three in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127447/is-it-possible-to-select-every-other-group-of-three-in-css)

Comment: This question was asked earlier than yours. Please check the dates next time. And if you think this question could have been asked better, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/7c3aw/
If you want your pattern to repeat every 6 elements (3 on, 3 off) use 6n.

```
div:nth-child(6n+4), div:nth-child(6n+5), div:nth-child(6n+6) {
    background-color:#0066cc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems so simple now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
:nth-child(6n+4), :nth-child(6n+5), :nth-child(6n+6) {
    CSS RULES
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/3HwU9/2/

The multiplier for n will be the length of your repeating pattern (in this case 6 because you have 3 off, and then 3 on), and then you add/subtract a number to pick out the right elements within the pattern (in this case, the 4th, 5th and 6th elements of the pattern).

Comment: Alternatively the :nth-of-type will achieve the same results.

Comment: Only if, like in my fiddle, all the children are of the same type. Change of one my `<p>` tags into a `<div>` and you'd get different results using `:nth-of-type`.