# Is it possible to select every other group of three in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to select every other group of three in CSS? And if it is; how?

So in the sample below apply style to the 4-6 and 10-12 `li`s.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
     <li>10</li>
     <li>11</li>
     <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

I know [pure] JavaScript and jQuery can do this but I am looking for a pure CSS solution if it exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS nth-child ignores the first 3 elements, stylize the other 3 and repeats. Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970189/css-nth-child-ignores-the-first-3-elements-stylize-the-other-3-and-repeats-pos)

Comment: Incidentally I found this tester after the fact but I thought it was important to link: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for nth-child:

```
ul li:nth-child(6n+4),ul li:nth-child(6n+5),ul li:nth-child(6n+6) {
    background:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/utEP4/1/

Comment: deja vu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970189/css-nth-child-ignores-the-first-3-elements-stylize-the-other-3-and-repeats-pos/ :)

Comment: +1 I fiddled around with the nth-child before I posted the question. I  figured some smart SOer would get it. I actually wanted every other 7 (for calendar rows) but figured every other 3 would be easier to replicate - http://jsfiddle.net/utEP4/8/. Thanks!

Comment: @BYossarian If that question was better asked I would have found it.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a **single selector**, using a combination of `:not` and `:nth-child`.

```
ul > li:not(:nth-child(6n+1)):not(:nth-child(6n+2)):not(:nth-child(6n+3))  {
    color:blue;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr9Pp/)

Using that selector by itself is pretty useless, though, considering you cannot style the other elements.

```
ul > li:not(:nth-child(6n+4)):not(:nth-child(6n+5)):not(:nth-child(6n+6))  {
    color:red;
}
```

Using a combination of both will allow you to style everything, [**see the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr9Pp/1/).