# How do I apply a style to every nth set of size m?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In css, you can apply a style to every `nth` item by using `:nth-child`:

```
li:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

This will make every 3rd row green. But what if I want to have my rows styled in a pattern of 3 white, 3 green, repeating?

```
 1  2  3 [4][5][6] 7  8  9 [10][11][12]
```

More complex: What if I wanted to have my rows styled in a pattern of 3 white, 2 green, repeating?

```
 1  2  3 [4][5] 6  7  8 [9][10] 11  12
```

And finally: What if I wanted to highlight only the remainder of the total length/3 (the positions in brackets)?

```
[1]
[1][2]
[1][2][3]
 1  2  3 [4]
 1  2  3 [4][5]
 1  2  3 [4][5][6]
 1  2  3  4  5  6 [7]
 1  2  3  4  5  6 [7][8]
 1  2  3  4  5  6 [7][8][9]
```

Is there a way to do these patterns in CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the comma operator like this:

```css
:nth-child(6n-2), /* 4, 10, 16, 22, ... */
:nth-child(6n-1), /* 5, 11, 17, 23, ... */
:nth-child(6n)    /* 6, 12, 18, 24, ... */
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
li:nth-child(6n-2),
li:nth-child(6n-1),
li:nth-child(6n) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>01</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li><li>11</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li></ul>
```

```css
:nth-child(5n-1), /* 4,  9, 14, 19, ... */
:nth-child(5n)    /* 5, 10, 15, 20, ... */
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
li:nth-child(5n-1),
li:nth-child(5n) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>01</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li><li>11</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li></ul>
```

And you can combine it with `:nth-last-child`:

```
li:nth-child(3n-2):nth-last-child(-n+3), /* is in 1,4,7,... and in the last 3 */
li:nth-child(3n-1):nth-last-child(-n+2), /* is in 2,5,8,... and in the last 2 */
li:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(-n+1)    /* is in 3,6,9,... and in the last 1 */
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
li:nth-child(3n-2):nth-last-child(-n+3),
li:nth-child(3n-1):nth-last-child(-n+2),
li:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(-n+1)
{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>01</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li><li>11</li></ul>
<ul><li>01</li><li>02</li><li>03</li><li>04</li><li>05</li><li>06</li><li>07</li><li>08</li><li>09</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li></ul>
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution for the first example. Nice! Would there be a way to apply it to only the remainder, solving for the last example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you?

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

> Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

Also found a similar question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19127514/2990234)

Example code from w3schools attached

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-child(3n+0) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3 you can input simple formulas of the form `a * n + b` the to the `:nth-child()` selector, written as `an + b`, where `a` and `b` are constants and `n` is a free variable. The style will then affect the elements whose position number match the expression for some *natural* value of `n` (integer >= 0). This means that `5n + 11` will match the 11th and 16th element, but not the 6th. [Source.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

This is the code you want:

```
li:nth-child(6n + 4), li:nth-child(6n + 5), li:nth-child(6n + 6) {
  background: green;
}
```

As for your second question:

```
li:nth-child(5n + 4), li:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  background: green;
}
```

I'm at loss with your last question, but it sounds feasible.