# CSS colour groups of 3

Tags: html, css

**The Problem:**

I am trying to work out the best method in which to implement alternating colours to a table in groups of 3. https://jsfiddle.net/94g0fqLr/

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>2011</th>
        <th>2012</th>
        <th>2013</th>
        <th>2014</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Group 1-->
        <tr>
            <td><b>Gross Margin</b></td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>15.0%</td>
            <td>16.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>19.9%</td>
            <td>22.7%</td>
            <td>22.6%</td>
            <td>23.3%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>21.2%</td>
            <td>22.3%</td>
            <td>26.4%</td>
            <td>27.5%</td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Group 2-->
        <!-- <tr> contents same as group 1 -->
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>

        <!-- Group 3-->
        <!-- <tr> contents same as group 1 -->
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is to alternatively colour every second **group**. i.e. `<tr>'s 1-3` will be white, `<tr>'s 4-6` will be grey, `<tr>'s 7-9` will be white again, and so on.

I have been fiddling with the `:nth-child` selector, using a series of :not()'s trying to get this to work, to no avail.

**The Question:**

Is there a pure CSS method to do this?
**Or**
Do I need to refactor the HTML, adding classes etc?
**Or**
Any better suggestions to achieve such?

Comment: dupes [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127447/is-it-possible-to-select-every-other-group-of-three-in-css), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970189/css-nth-child-ignores-the-first-3-elements-stylize-the-other-3-and-repeats-pos/)

Comment: @daniel Thanks.. These didn't come up though when I was making this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is a pure CSS approach that doesn't require you to refactor your HTML.

Assuming that your groups are always going to be groups of 3, you can use `6n+1`, `6n+2`, and `6n+3` to color your groups in an alternating way:

**Live Demo:**

```css
table th, table td{
 padding: 5px 30px;
}
table tr:nth-child(6n+1), table tr:nth-child(6n+2), table tr:nth-child(6n+3){
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>2011</th>
        <th>2012</th>
        <th>2013</th>
        <th>2014</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Group 1-->
        <tr>
            <td><b>Gross Margin</b></td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>15.0%</td>
            <td>16.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>19.9%</td>
            <td>22.7%</td>
            <td>22.6%</td>
            <td>23.3%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>21.2%</td>
            <td>22.3%</td>
            <td>26.4%</td>
            <td>27.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Group 2-->
        <tr>
            <td><b>EBITDA/Interest</b></td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>15.0%</td>
            <td>16.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>19.9%</td>
            <td>22.7%</td>
            <td>22.6%</td>
            <td>23.3%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>21.2%</td>
            <td>22.3%</td>
            <td>26.4%</td>
            <td>27.5%</td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Group 3-->
        <tr>
            <td><b>EBIT/Interest</b></td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>15.0%</td>
            <td>16.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>19.9%</td>
            <td>22.7%</td>
            <td>22.6%</td>
            <td>23.3%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>21.2%</td>
            <td>22.3%</td>
            <td>26.4%</td>
            <td>27.5%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/94g0fqLr/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to give the rows a class

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>2011</th>
        <th>2012</th>
        <th>2013</th>
        <th>2014</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Group 1-->
        <tr class="group1">
            <td><b>Gross Margin</b></td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>14.5%</td>
            <td>15.0%</td>
            <td>16.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="group1">
            <td></td>
            <td>19.9%</td>
            <td>22.7%</td>
            <td>22.6%</td>
            <td>23.3%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="group1">
            <td></td>
            <td>21.2%</td>
            <td>22.3%</td>
            <td>26.4%</td>
            <td>27.5%</td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Group 2-->
        <!-- <tr class="group2"> contents same as group 1 -->
        <tr class="group2"></tr>
        <tr class="group2"></tr>
        <tr class="group2"></tr>

        <!-- Group 3-->
        <!-- <tr class="group1"> contents same as group 1 -->
        <tr class="group1"></tr>
        <tr class="group1"></tr>
        <tr class="group1"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then target each with CSS

```css
.group1 
{
    background:white;
}

.group2 
{
    background:grey;
}
```